# The value of the series $1+\frac {1}{2}+\frac {1}{4}+\frac {1}{8}+ \cdots$ is?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The value of the series $1+\dfrac {1}{2}+\dfrac {1}{4}+\dfrac {1}{8}+\cdots$ is:

$1$. $2$

$2$. $3$

$3$. $\dfrac {1}{4}$

$4$. $1$.

My Attempt:

The given series is a geometric series.

First term $(a)=1$

Common ratio $(r)=\dfrac {1}{2}$

So, I couldn't move from here. What does the question want us to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call $S = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots$. Then

\begin{eqnarray}
2S  &=& 2\left( 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots\right) \\ 
&=& 2 + 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots \\
&=& 2 + S
\end{eqnarray}

Therefore

$$
S = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots = 2
$$

Comment: Why/How is $2S=2+1+\dfrac {1}{2}+..$?

Comment: @Maxwell Just multiply every term within the brackets by 2

Answer (score 0):

Since the first $n$ terms have sum $a\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$, for $|r|<1$ the $n\to\infty$ limit is $\frac{a}{1-r}$, which in your case is $2$. By the way, don't add an $\infty$ symbol after the ellipsis for an infinite series.

Answer (score 0):

In general for a GP with $n$ terms we have $S_n =\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r} $ where $r$ is the common ratio and $r\neq 1$ and $a$ is the first term.

So if we have $|r|<1$, then as $n\to \infty$:

$ S_n\to \frac{a}{1-r} =\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}} =2$

Comment: Why/How is $S_n=\dfrac {a}{1-r}$

Comment: @Maxwell I'm saying that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}S_n = \frac{a}{1-r},\quad |r|<1$. This is because $r^n\to 0$

Answer (score 0):

Let's rewrite the sum:
$$
1+\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\dots=\lim_{N\to+\infty}\sum_{n=0}^N\left(\frac12\right)^n
$$

Observe now that for $q\in\Bbb R$, $q\neq1$ we have
\begin{align*}
(1-q)\sum_{n=0}^Nq^n=(1-q)(1+q+q^2+\dots+q^N)=1-q^{N+1}
\end{align*}
from which
$$
\sum_{n=0}^Nq^n=\frac{1-q^{N+1}}{1-q}
$$

so in your case, we have to plug $q=1/2$ and passing to the limit. Can you conclude?

Answer (score 0):

The [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) is given below:
$$a+ar+a^2+ar^3+\dots=\frac{a}{1-r}\quad\text{for $|r|<1$}.$$

So, in your question, we have $$\overbrace{1+\frac{1}{2}+\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^3+\dots}^{\text{where $a=1$ and $r=\frac{1}{2}$}}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=2.$$